# jquery autocomplete categories with label metadata

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am able to do basic labels and categories using http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

However, I was wondering if its possible to attach some metadata with label. For eg. right now I have

```
Product
  TV
  DVD
People
  James
  ROY
```

I want to something like

```
Product
  TV - Electronics
  DVD - Electronics
People
  James - USA
  ROY - UK
```

When user hits enter on selected item label, I only want label text in input box and I do not want meta data as part of input text. That means I dont want Electronics as part of input text.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add metadata to label,text to idx field that would like to display in textbox and then handle select event to show idx text in input field ike:

**CODE:**

```
 $(function() {
var data = [
    { label: "TV - Electronics",idx:"TV", category: "Products" },
{ label: "DVD - Electronics",idx:"DVD", category: "Products" },
{ label: "James - USA",idx:"James", category: "People" },
{ label: "Roy - UK",idx:"Roy", category: "People" }
];
$( "#search" ).catcomplete({
delay: 0,
source: data,
    select: function(event, ui) { 
    event.preventDefault();
  var selectedObj = ui.item.idx;
  $("#search").val(selectedObj);  
}
});
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fS7Tz/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: but then metadata becomes part of input text...I only want metadata to be displayed ...but when the item is selected, I dont want metadata to be part of input text.

Answer (score 0):

As @Unknown says, you can return other properties than the Autocomplete standards (`label`, `value`) in your `items` dataset.

I have UI where I offer "create new " as an option, if the user an recognized name, as well as offering existing entities. This uses an extra PK/or Create property, which is stored into a hidden input on selection.

For customizing rendering, you can distinguish between the "nicely rendered" value (which you display) and the back-end key or value (for use internally). Depends how you want to implement your UI, but one option is a "dictionary"/ "associative array" approach in Javascript to look the values up.